# How can I show alert message on the desktop

Tags: fedora, mate-desktop, messaging

I am using Fedora 20 with a MATE desktop and the Z shell.

Is there a way to display a message on the screen somewhere, sent from a shell program, when the terminal window is not visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zenity` (GTK+ dialog display):

```
zenity --warning --text="Warning text" --title="Warning title"
```

Change `--warning` to `--error` or `--info` for different window versions. And as always: `man zenity` is your friend.

Comment: Can also use `conky` or `dzen2`...

Comment: Thank you jimmij for that answer, and for the reminder of zenity which I had completely forgotten about. It works exactly as I wanted.